# Programmatically Polling the Build Farm

Tags: ros, binaries, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best way to programmatically get the status of packages on the build farm? Is there an API? The [status page](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html) does some sneaky javascripting, so scraping the HTML does not work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187856/programmatically-polling-the-build-farm/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The HTML of the debbuild status page is regenerated every 15 minutes. The Javascript is only doing some client-side filtering - no polling of data.

You also don't have to parse the HTML itself. The HTML is generated from the data in the CSV files which are available in the same location: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/

So you can e.g. poll http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.csv to create your own status page / monitoring system.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-25**:
This is useful. Two things:

1. The html itself does not seem to contain the different build information. If you read the source HTML, that data is filled in dynamically somewhere.
2. The CSVs do not contain maintainer information, which I imagine can just be crossreferenced with the rosdistro info

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-07-25**:
Yes, the CSV data is cross referenced with information available via rosdistro. If you want to see what is actually done the script generating these files is https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm/blob/master/scripts/generate_status_page.py

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Jenkins does appear to have an [API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).

Edit: There's more info at http://jenkins.ros.org/api/

For example, you can load everything in python as follows:

```
 builddata = ast.literal_eval(urllib.urlopen('http://jenkins.ros.org/api/python').read())
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-07-25**:
Please do NOT poll our Jenkins server programmatically. It would likely result in a much higher load - especially if more people would do that. Otherwise we would need to prevent those kind of queries (and we would actually prefer to work on ROS related stuff rather then "protecting" the infrastructure).

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-07-25**:
Good to know. Might be good to disable those APIs to prevent that from happening. If one wanted that data, would it be possible to maybe setup a cron job to periodically generate a static XML/JSON/python file to use?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-07-25**:
We don't want to disable them since we use some of the APIs for certain tasks. If you have specific information in mind which you want to use please describe them and provide the job configuration for performing the task. If it does not cost much resources we can easily add this to the farm.